# How do I add multiple optional parameters in Express in same route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters

Big fan of Stackoverflow and this is my first question ever on it! I'm working on a javascript express project and trying to figure out if I can do this under one get request. I'm having a hard time figuring this out

```
app.get("/test/:q1&:q2&:q3", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params)
})
```

Basically, when the user looks up the following routes, I want the following result in req.params when these get requests are made. I want to keep it under one get request if possible.

TO CLARIFY. The above code CAN change to meet the functional requirements BELOW. Below CANNOT change

```
"http://localhost:3000/test/hello" --->
req.params will equal { q1: "hello" }

"http://localhost:3000/test/hello&world" --->
req.params will equal { q1: "hello", q2: "world" }

"http://localhost:3000/test/hello&world&foobar" --->
req.params will equal { q1: "hello", q2: "world", q3: "foobar" }
```

I tried using the "?" in the query but it seems to only work on new routes followed by a "/", not within the same route. I'm thinking I'll have to go with the quick and dirty solution of making 2 more get requests for each scenario. Currently when I try putting in "/test/hello&world"  or "/test/hello", it will crash and will only work if I have all 3 parts filled.

Comment: can't you use query ?

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/test?q1=hello&q2=world`

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I wish I could explain the question better but I have a hard time knowing the term names

Comment: ```http://localhost:3000/test/?q1=hello&q2=world```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232679/how-to-access-optional-url-parameters-in-express-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```js
app.get('/test/:string', (req, res) => {
  const str = req.params.string
  const params = str.split('&')
    .reduce((acc, curr, i) => ({ ...acc, [`q${i + 1}`]: curr }), {})

  // params => { q1: 'hello', q2: 'world', q3: 'foobar' }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually is an acceptable substitute. Was hoping for something within express query that would allow it but this will do

Comment: Glad I helped :D